# couldn't open the software-center and sources

Tags: software-center, ppa

Failed to download repository information

```
W:GPG error: (http)://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 464AD83D4631BBEA, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bisigi/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bisigi/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've try all the way from the question 'failed to download repository information'

thanks for the help

Comment: I'd guess that a search will find a duplicate for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go here

http://ppa.launchpad.net/bisigi/ppa/ubuntu/dists/

You can see that saucy is not a version that is available.

That's confirmed from the PPA page.

https://launchpad.net/~bisigi/+archive/ppa

Open Software sources from the dash - go to the other software tab and disable this PPA and reload.

Look at [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The thing is I can't open the software sources, everytime i try that, the 'failed to download repository information' comes out. neither can i open the software & update.

Comment: @user212064 - if you can't open the GUI then there are instructions in the same referred page to editing the sources list files manually using a text editor. The ppa(s) you are having problems with will be in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Comment: thanks a lot, it works. i get rid of the errors messages. but i still cannot open software & updater or software source.